# How do I leave a Multi-national Corporation (MNC)?

Tags: company-culture, india, politics, relieving-letter

I am trying to leave an MNC because the project that I am working on is pretty much useless and I am not gaining any knowledge and other teams do not provide necessary support and also the pay is small.

The most important thing is there is too much internal politics. My superiors don't want me to leave. They are ready to increase my pay but I still don't want to work in this corp.

What do I do? Any guidance will be really helpful.

Comment: Since I suspect your question might be really about getting a relieving letter, I suggest you look at the [tag:relieving-letter] questions

Comment: Leave if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the issue you are having is that you do not know how to say you want to leave and remain firm when managers tell you they don't want you to.  I recommend:

- Write a resignation letter and send a copy to your HR department.
- Tell your immediate manager that you have just submitted your resignation letter.
- Have a simple stock phrase to repeat when people press you on it.  Something like "I'm very sorry, but I have already made my decision."  If they keep pressing you, you can just repeat variations on it:  "I understand, and thank you for the offer, but I have already made my decision", "Wow, that's a kind offer, but as I say, I have already made my decision".  Do not get into a debate about it, just keep repeating (almost) the same thing.

Comment: You don't say "I want to leave". You say "I am leaving".

Answer (score 4):

1. Check your contract to see how much notice you are required to give.
2. Find a job you expect to like better than the current one, remembering that any organization with three or more people will have internal politics.
3. Deliver written notice of your resignation, conforming to the notice requirements, to HR and your manager.

Comment: 4. Profit! (as they say)

Comment: 3 or more? 1 or more ...

Comment: I agree...
1) Find a job FIRST before you step out of that door for the last time.
2) Notify in resignation mail: You last day in office..Ask him/her to reply back 
3)  Spend most time finding a suitable job but find a job that you might actually like.
4) Last but most important rule.. You must never stay back in a company after you resign no matter how lucrative the return offer looks. 
5) Never tell current company that you got a job. You say: You have some good opportunities. You will be finalizing one soon.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to work there, don't... Give notice according to your contract and find another job.

Comment: But preferably in the reverse order!

Comment: @JanDoggen Maybe, but I find that having an absolute date for when the money runs out is a fantastic motivator to find the next source of income.

Comment: @JohnHC But this motivator might also cause you to end up with a worse source then the one you left.